# Nowhere dense set with positive Lebesgue measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I'm looking for a subset $A$ of $\mathbb R$ such that $A$ is a nowhere dense set with positive Lebesgue measure.

Comment: The canonical answer to this question is *[Fat Cantor Set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith-Volterra-Cantor_set)*

Answer (score 8):

The example you are looking for is given in this [page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nowhere_dense_set)